# ExtJS 4.1.1 | Why `view` and `this` are different in event handler function of inherited class

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I wrote my own `My.grid` inherited from `Ext.grid.Panel` and set listener on `itemdblclick` event.

Handler function of this event gets `view` as the first argument and has `this` as the scope.

I don't understand why I get different values in `view` and `this`?

- `this` is an instance of `My.grid`
- `view` is an instance of `Ext.grid.Panel` (but I expect `My.grid`)

May be I'm doing something wrong? or is it a bug/feature of ExtJS?

How to write inherited widgets there `view` refs to inherited object?

This is quick example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ExtJS Test page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'change'],
            data: {
                'items': [
                    { 'name': 'Lisa', 'email': 'lisa@simpsons.com', 'change': 100 },
                    { 'name': 'Bart', 'email': 'bart@simpsons.com', 'change': -20 },
                    { 'name': 'Homer', 'email': 'home@simpsons.com', 'change': 23 },
                    { 'name': 'Marge', 'email': 'marge@simpsons.com', 'change': -11 }
                ]
            },
            proxy: { type: 'memory', reader: { type: 'json', root: 'items' } }
        });

        Ext.define('MY.grid', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
            alias: 'widget.simpsonsgrid',
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [
                { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
                { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email' },
                { header: 'Change', dataIndex: 'change' }
            ],
            initComponent: function () {
                this.callParent(arguments);
                this.on('itemdblclick', this.test, this);
            },
            test: function (view, record) {
                console.log(this); // instance of My.grid
                console.log(view); // instance of Ext.grid.Panel
            }
        });

        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.widget('simpsonsgrid', {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
        });
    </script>
</head> <body></body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into API (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel). You can see there that this particular event has following signature:

```
itemdblclick(
    Ext.view.View this,
    Ext.data.Model record,
    HTMLElement item,
    Number index,
    Ext.EventObject e,
    Object eOpts
)
```

So actually you should get an istance of `Ext.grid.View` in `view` argument. You can get instance of `MY.grid` by accessing `view.ownerCt`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TLEFH/

Comment: `view.ownerCt` This is exactly that I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: You can also query up: view.up('grid').

Comment: `view.up('grid')` I know this solution and it makes sense, but intuitively I don't like use string searching engine when I can just throw the exact variable. Lolo gave me exactly that perfectly works for me.